# Applying a custom filter to several columns of a datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatable

first of all, sorry for my english. I have a small problem with a datatable filter and my inexperience with javascript(ajax/jquery is hurting me when it comes to deal with it.

To put it in context. I have a php view that shows a datatable with the data it receives from an ajax call, which is the one I show below, as well as the way I format it in the table (I omit columns because between columns 2 and 17 it is the same code):

```
ajax: {
        url: "controller.php",
        dataType: "JSON",
        dataSrc: "",
        data: () => ({
            action: "getUsersCookies",

        }),
        error: (error) => {
            if (error.responseJSON) {
                alertify.error(error.responseJSON.message);
                $("#table > tbody").html(`
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="100" style="text-align:center">Se ha producido un error, por favor intentelo de nuevo.</td>
                            </tr>
                        `);
            }
        },
    },

    lengthMenu: [
        [-1],
        ["Todos"],
    ],
    iDisplayLength: -1,
    lengthChange: false,
    order: [
        [0, "desc"],
    ],
    autoWidth: false,
    columns: [{
            data: 'fecha',
            name: 'fecha',
            className: "text-center",
            render: (date) => moment(date).format("DD/MM/YYYY"),
        },
        {
            data: 'nombre',
            name: 'nombre',
            className: "text-left",
        },
        {
            data: 'cookie1',
            name: 'cookie1',
            className: "text-center",
            render: (planType) => {
                if (!planType) return "";
                const badgeColor = planType === "1" ? "success" : "danger";
                const badgeText = planType === "1" ? "Si" : "No";
                return `<span class="badge badge-plan-type badge-${badgeColor}">${badgeText}</span>`
            },
        },
        {
            data: 'cookie2',
            name: 'cookie2',
            className: "text-center",
            render: (planType) => {
                if (!planType) return "";
                const badgeColor = planType === "1" ? "success" : "danger";
                const badgeText = planType === "1" ? "Si" : "No";
                return `<span class="badge badge-plan-type badge-${badgeColor}">${badgeText}</span>`
            },
        },
```

The view works well because it shows me the data as I need it:

[Datatable Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iOFQi.png)

From here comes the problem. As you can see, I have a select that allows me to show all the data, show those rows that have all the columns between 2 and 17 with values 'Yes' and finally an option that shows me those rows that contain at least one 'No' in the columns from 2 to 17. I mean, you show me the rows that have only one 'No' or have 16 'No'. To do this I created this code:

```
$('#CookiesFilter').on('change', function() {
    var select = $(this).val();

    if (select === '2') {
        table.columns([2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17]).search('Si').draw();
    } else if (select === '3') {
        table.columns([2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17]).search('No').draw();
    } else {
        table.columns([2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17]).search('').draw();
    }
});
```

As it is, the first option works for me, the second one too, but in the third one it only shows me those rows that have everything set to No (which I know is normal because I'm telling it precisely that) But no matter how many times I've tried solutions I can't get a filter that does what I really want it to do. For example, using the image above, the filter should show me the first two rows, but currently it doesn't show me any of them.

Can you help me with this problem?

I would like to get a solution that manages to do what the filter is asking me to do, as currently I only get the users that have marked all to No and it should be those that have marked at least one.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] which we can easily run for ourselves. I expect that would be a _very_ much simpler version of your actual code - with just enough data and columns to show the _specific_ problem you are trying to solve. It probably doesn't even need Ajax - just some hard-coded JavaScript data which matches your JSON. You can provide this as a [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/12567365).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi @andrewJames. I think I've managed to solve it (or at least now I'm getting the result I was looking for). I have applied the following code and it works:

```
else if (select === '3') {
        $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
            function(settings, data, dataIndex) {
                for (let i = 2; i <= 17; i++) {
                    if (data[i] === "No") {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        );

        table.draw();
```

Comment: That's great! If you want to, you can write a proper answer, showing the solution and explaining how it works. That will be useful for future visitors to your question.